# local: -n: invalid option

Tags: bash, ubuntu

When executing script with `./script` i see 
local: -n: invalid option

my test script: `cat script`

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -Ax BINS_TO_ARCH_FILE=(
 ["file1"]="test/file1"
 ["file2"]="test/file2"
 ["file3"]="test/file3"
);

function archive-bz2()
{
  local -n DO_NOT_USE_THIS_NAME="$1";

  for path_to_archive in "${!DO_NOT_USE_THIS_NAME[@]}"; do
    echo "path_to_archive: $path_to_archive";
  done
}

archive-bz2 BINS_TO_ARCH_FILE
```

But when i execute it in a subshell with

```
bash script
```

it is working...

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.0(1)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I tested it also with older bash version and both ways are working fine :(
on both local is build in command

```
type local
local is a shell builtin

bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Comment: Whats the -n option to local supposed to do?

Comment: When u pass the array as parameter and if your local variable is not with -n option as output i see path_to_archive: 0

Comment: The point of using `-n` is that you don't need to use `!` in the parameter expansion.

Comment: It's not clear how many versions of `bash` you have installed or where they are installed. What do `/bin/bash --version` and `which bash` output?

Comment: I tested it on 2 different ubuntu machines 4.4.0(1)-release and 4.3.11(1)-release both in /bin/bash

Comment: Ok i found another bash version installed with which -a :) that was the reason

Answer (score 0):

This is an old trick and works great for me in both scenarios so I guess it must be some bug in your distro...

Per manual:
`-n` means that `DO_NOT_USE_THIS_NAME` is a reference to variable named by the $1 (`BINS_TO_ARCH_FILE`)

This is why `archive-bz2 BINS_TO_ARCH_FILE` will work, note the missing `$` and `[@]`
so it can be used to insert complex arguments to a function.

Please note that a reference works in both directions so the function can also update the value of `BINS_TO_ARCH_FILE` so you can use this way to extract values from function instead of limited return.

`local` is almost similar with `declare`
https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/declare