# in bash what does the -n parameter in "local -n" mean?

Tags: linux, bash, local

in bash what does the -n parameter in `local -n var...` mean? - how does it differ from `local var...`

I can't find a good example / explanation for it. There are no man pages for keywords (it seems?). The closest I have found is a comment here: [local: -n: invalid option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40237782/local-n-invalid-option) - which suggests something about not using `!` param expansion

Comment: There aren't _separate_ man pages but `man bash | less "+/^SHELL BUILTIN/"` will take you there, or just do `help local` which points you to `help declare` (`help` itself is a builtin). And yes `-n` here is a nameref with the same effect as using `${!namevar}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parameters to `local` are unfortunately not documented in `help local`, but in `help declare`:

> ```
>  `-n` make NAME a reference to the variable named by its value
> ```

How does it work?

```bash
#! /bin/bash
f () {
    local -n x=y
    y=12
    x=42
    echo $x $y  # 42 42
}
f
```

You can achieve similar behaviour with the `!` indirection (that's what the comment in the linked question means):

```bash
#! /bin/bash
f () {
    x=y
    y=12
    echo ${!x}  # 12
}
f
```

Answer (score 6):

`-n` declares the variable to be a [*nameref*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameters):

> A variable can be assigned the *nameref* attribute using the `-n` option to the `declare` or `local` builtin commands (see [Bash Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins)) to create a *nameref*, or a reference to another variable. This allows variables to be manipulated indirectly. Whenever the nameref variable is referenced, assigned to, unset, or has its attributes modified (other than using or changing the nameref attribute itself), the operation is actually performed on the variable specified by the nameref variable’s value. A nameref is commonly used within shell functions to refer to a variable whose name is passed as an argument to the function. For instance, if a variable name is passed to a shell function as its first argument, running
>
> ```
> declare -n ref=$1
> ```
>
> inside the function creates a nameref variable *ref* whose value is the variable name passed as the first argument. References and assignments to *ref*, and changes to its attributes, are treated as references, assignments, and attribute modifications to the variable whose name was passed as `$1`.

It's worth noting that namerefs and `-n` were [added in Bash 5](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/NEWS?h=bash-5.0) (January 2019).